# Create an iptable or BPF rule to only allow OpenVPN traffic to a connection port 1194 and drop all other traffic going to that port

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ddos, bpf

How's it going everyone? I am trying to create either an iptable or a BPF rule which will only allow OpenVPN traffic over UDP to my VPN server on destination port 1194 in the hopes of preventing DDoS attacks to that port whilst still being able to connect to it. I would normally implement a simple whitelist of me and my friends' ips however one of them has a dynamic IP which changes very regularly so constantly updating my firewall to allow traffic from his IP would be somewhat annoying aha. If it could also only allow windows users to connect that would be great as well as me and my two buddies run windows and this would be one more parameter the traffic has to match in order to be accepted. Any help in creating this rule would be greatly appreciated as my cheap little personal VPN for some reason has been DDoS over 5 times this week while my friends and I play GTA - perhaps that's the reason! Thanks in advance to anyone who can chime in here!

I have tried the following rules but unfortunately to no avail:

#Allow packets with the string "OpenVPN" to my connection port then drop remaining UDP traffic to that port
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -m string --algo bm --string "OpenVPN" --to 65535 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j DROP

After flushing my iptables and adding these two rules, I was expecting to be able to connect to my VPN server through OpenVPN but unfortunately I was unable to connect.

Comment: From the iptables tag: IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/). Please delete this.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to tell if incoming traffic originates from an OpenVPN application or not. The only way to validate that would be to see if the contents of your UDP packet looks like an OpenVPN protocol header, does the size match, does it contain magic numbers or do certain fields contain the values you expect. So it would require fairly intimate knowledge of the OpenVPN protocol to pull that off.

Additionally, UDP is inherently susceptible to DDoS attacks because of UDP amplification. Even if you were to manage the above, its trivial for most DDoS attackers to just saturate your uplink, making any filtering useless.

Switching to TCP will make it a bit more difficult since launching TCP attacks requires more resources for the same amount of traffic and the three-way handshake offers a good place to enforce proper TCP clients and/or implement IP blacklists.

Ultimately, the only real way to deal with DDoS attacks are to seek protection using DDoS mitigation/protection companies like Cloudflare, Akamai, Imperva, ect. which unfortunately are not free most of the time.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input, I have managed to find that in all OpenVPN packets used to initiate a connection with my server the byte value at byte 42 is 38, I believe can also be written as 0x38 if I'm not mistaken. I would like to create an iptables rule which allows only packets which contain the value 38 at byte 42 to be accepted, do you know how I would write this out? I tried using the u32 option but unfortunately it is not accepting the traffic I need. Here is what I tried:
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -m u32 --u32 "42&0xFF=0x38" -j ACCEPT